# 2 questions about tags

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-wiki-excerpts

**Question #1**:
There is a [corpus](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/corpus) tag and a [corpora](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/corpora) tag... *Shouldn't we merge them?* They are basically the same thing. I suggest merging them and keeping just one.

**Question #2**:
I was trying to write the wiki excerpt for the [etymology](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) tag, but I couldn't find any "create tag wiki" or something similar like I did with another tag... *Is there a reason for this?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) I agree we should merge these. I am not sure anyone yet has the tag rep to [suggest a synonym](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/tags/corpora/synonyms) yet. On English.se I think we generally chose to use the plural versions of tags like this as the main tag and make the others synonyms of that - we might consider doing the same here.

2) When you click the [etymology](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) "help us create it" link, currently, and it goes [here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/tags/etymology/info), at the bottom I see that there is "edit pending" instead of the "edit" link. My best guess is that this blocks others from editing until someone handles the current suggested edit. I think it requires 1500 rep to approve these edits so you are close :)

Comment: Thanks! So that means someone else already suggested an edit. I see... It seemed nobody did earlier, and it looked weird to me. Now it makes more sense! About the suggesting, I will as soon as I gain the reputation. Thanks again!

Comment: Yep I made the plural corpora on purpose so that we could merge the singular corpus into it as soon as somebody has enough rep to do so (-:

Comment: I think until some of us have enough rep to approve each others edits only the Stack Exchange employees can approve tag wiki edits. It seems they only check them periodically and that they further aren't sure whether to approve some of the pending edits so are leaving some for a while for now.

Comment: One suggestion: perhaps we should make [tag:corpus-linguistics] also be a synonym of the other two.

Comment: It is *possible* to imagine different definitions for corpus and corpora but I don't think we *should* as they partly overlap anyway. *corpus-linguistics* is a bit more unique but I don't think we gain anything by having a separate tag. And AFAIK nobody has tag-synonym-rights yet. Is that 2000 wuffie?